# How to print word triangle in main method?

Tags: java

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class TriangleOne
{
    private String word;

    public TriangleOne()
    {
        word="";
    }

    public TriangleOne(String s)
    {
        word = s;
    }

    public void setWord(String s)
    {
        word = s;
    }

    public void print( )
    {
        int a = word.length();
        for (int i = a; i>=0; i --)
        {
            System.out.println(word.substring(0,i));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the runner.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class TriangleOneRunner
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        TriangleOne test = new TriangleOne();
        test.setWord("hippo");
        System.out.println(test);

    }
}
```

This prints out 'TriangeOne@1e9c23b'
I want this to print out

```
hippo
hipp
hip
hi
h
```

What should I fix?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling the `print()` method?

Comment: How do I call print() method in the runner? I'm new to java, sorry.

Comment: We're all new at some point, don't worry. But you wrote the print method for a reason, right? How did you expect to use it?

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ the official tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling test.print() and not System.out.print()

Comment: Your welcome. Also do some research before starting to learn java the link given by @Kayaman

Comment: Don't start at tutorialspoint. It's very unreliable (in some places it's absolutely awful, there are other unreliable tutorial sites like that too). Trust only the official tutorial.

Comment: Oh! then my bad. Will surely keep this in mind. Thanks @Kayaman.